# Performance statistics on wildfly

Tags: jboss, profiling, monitoring, performance-testing, wildfly

I have been researching of a tool to measure the performance in an application deployed on WildFly server.

I need to measure following scenarios:

> (1) client order -> (2) hit the server -> (3) start processing the order -> (4) Call service_1 -> (5) call service_2 ->
>   (6) processed the order successfully and ready to send -> (7) client
>   receive the response

Requirements

1. Monitor time taken in each step: ex: 1 to 7, 3 to 6, 3 to 5
2. How to monitor, profile in the server: I checked [Jboss Profiler](http://jbossprofiler.jboss.org/),
   [Visual VM](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/monitoring-wildfly-using-visualvm)

As I have listed I could find many tools for 2nd requirement, But I couldn't find good resource for first requirement. Could someone please point me to some  tools (or some ways to) do this.

Comment: You should probably visit [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and ask for the recommendation there. Also visit the Stack Overflow [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what's on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

check out Sightline performance tool - they can collect data from OS all the way through java stack - very good history trail and analysis capabilities too.

Comment: Usually this type of answer is deleted, but the question kind of begged it. Be careful about answering questions with "link-only answers" and "answer that are opinions".

Comment: The question itself is off-topic because it asks for recommendations.